# Why Can't use marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, notifications

Hello guys i try to use Laravel notification package But When I Run This command in terminal

```
composer require marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify
```

Here I Have This Error

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\EShop>composer require marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify  
Using version ^1.0 for marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify ^1.0 -> satisfiable by marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify[v1.0.0].
    - marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify v1.0.0 requires illuminate/contracts ~6.0|~7.0|~8.0 -> found illuminate/contracts[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-de
v] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify:*" to figure out if any version is installable
, or "composer require marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I Try to use These Commands But Doesn't Work

```
   composer require marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify:*

composer require marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify:^2.1"
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel 9.0?

Comment: @miken32 No I'm Using Laravel 9.21

Comment: Error message is pretty clear then. "marjose/laravel-bootstrap-notify v1.0.0 requires illuminate/contracts ~6.0|~7.0|~8.0"

Comment: @miken32 Yes This Is Error What Can I Do to fix it

Comment: Obviously you can use Laravel 6, 7, or 8.